# Erro ao conectar com DB postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

Estou tentando rodar um sistema e no ultimo step ele apresenta um erro de falha na conexão com banco de dados

```
Database creation error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

dentro do ubuntu ele aparece a seguinte msg

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

o que poderia estar falhando? `psql -l` mostra que o server esta ativo

Comment: Pelo que entendi, falta iniciar o serviço, qual a saída do comando `psql -l`?

Comment: List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)